# How to combine elements from two lists into a third?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `a` and `b`:

```
a  =   [3,    6,   8,   65,   3]
b  =   [34,   2,   5,   3,    5]

c gets [3/34, 6/2, 8/5, 65/3, 3/5]
```

Is it possible to obtain their ratio in Python, like in variable `c` above?

I tried `a/b` and got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: Define 'ratio' of two lists.

Comment: And what was your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by list ratio?

Answer (score 44):

```
>>> from __future__ import division # floating point division in Py2x
>>> a=[3,6,8,65,3]
>>> b=[34,2,5,3,5]
>>> [x/y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[0.08823529411764706, 3.0, 1.6, 21.666666666666668, 0.6]
```

Or in `numpy` you can do `a/b`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([3,6,8,65,3], dtype=np.float)
>>> b=np.array([34,2,5,3,5], dtype=np.float)
>>> a/b
array([  0.08823529,   3.        ,   1.6       ,  21.66666667,   0.6       ])
```

Comment: Actually it depends on what the OP meant with "dividing lists". Suppose he wanted to interpret it in the sense of set fraction (e.g. elements which appear in both lists).

Comment: Guessing is for comments, not for answers. Actually, the first thing I thought was `A\B` set fraction.

Comment: @esseks actually it's fine to post answers of what you think they question means if you are pretty sure you are correct and if OP says it isn't what they want I will delete my answer

Comment: @ esseks With a/b I meant the division of the first element in a by the first element in b and so on. The answer received is essentially what I was looking for. 
@ jamylak Thanks for both the answers, it is useful to know different ways to get the same result.

Answer (score 21):

The built-in [*map()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) function makes short work of these kinds of problems:

```
>>> from operator import truediv
>>> a=[3,6,8,65,3]
>>> b=[34,2,5,3,5]
>>> map(truediv, a, b)
[0.08823529411764706, 3.0, 1.6, 21.666666666666668, 0.6]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! when doing this from sql queries transformed to lists in numpy I get `argument 2 to map() must support iteration` do you have any idea on how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using list comprehension (element by element):

```
div = [ai/bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)]
```

Note that if you want float division, you need to specify this (or make the original values floats):

```
fdiv = [float(ai)/bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: Or do `from __future__ import division`, or use Python 3 (as the OP may well be already).

Comment: @lvc - I don't like making an import that can completely change the meaning of code unless absolutely necessary.  A significant amount of the code I write would break spectacularly if I did `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3,6,8,65,3]
>>> b = [34,2,5,3,5]
>>> [(x*1.0)/y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[0.08823529411764706, 3.0, 1.6, 21.666666666666668, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.divide`

```
c=np.divide(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
a  =   [3,    6,   8,   65,   3]
b  =   [34,   2,   5,   3,    5]

c = [float(x)/y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
print(c)
```