# divide two list of numbers in python (using list comprehension and not using zip)

Tags: python, list, divide

i'm fairly new to python Language . I have two list like this:
***and i don't install the numpy package yet .***

```
First_List = [10, 2, 5, 4, 100]

Second_List = [5, 10, 20, 20, 25]
```

How can I Divide each element in `First_List` by elements in the `Second_List`? 
The output should be:

```
Result = [2, 0.2, 0.2, 4]
```

and i want a List in the output, and not an array ! how can i do this ? 
i try using this :

```
>>> First_List = [10, 2, 5, 4, 100]
>>> Second_List = [5, 10, 20, 20, 25]
>>> First_List/Second_List
```

but i got this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       First_List/Second_List TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: `[x/y for x,y in zip(First_List,Second_List)]`?

Comment: Show what you have tried already so we can point you in the right direction. If you show your code, the community will be able to actually help explain to you what mistakes you are making, which will be a much better learning lesson than just being given the answer.

Comment: @NimaGeran Please do not put code in the comments. That is extremely unhelpful. Edit your question and put the code in there, and use the formatting tools so that it is readable and understandable for other readers.

Comment: i try using numpy to do that but i don't get what i need .

Comment: @NimaGeran Do you have to use numpy to solve this? Or did you decide to use numpy because you think you need it? Because this is definitely not something that *needs* numpy.

Comment: "i don't get what i need" is not describing a problem

Comment: But, numpy *does* make things very easy for this type of operation. Numpy's solution is certainly more readable than `[x/y for x,y in zip(a,b)]`...

Comment: But, why install a whole package for the argument that it is more readable? That is ridiculously overkill. Furthermore, what you wrote is very readable, also, there is nothing wrong with "exploding" that to make it even more readable if that is *not* readable enough.

Comment: @NimaGeran Based on the code you just showed, you really need to revise why list division like that does not work and you need to actually iterate through your lists and divide the *numbers* among each other. Please refer back to your course notes or whatever tutorial you are following to know how to divide numbers inside a list

Comment: @idjaw i dont install numpy yet, is there a way to not install it ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `x/y` assumes Python 3 because of floor division, also with Python 3 it always `return`s a `float` (e.g. `10 / 5` is `2.0`) and they want an `int` here apparently

Comment: BTW, an entry is missing in `Result`:  4/20 = 0.2

Comment: Thank you for your comments friends !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming both `First_List` and `Second_List` have same number of elements, you can iterate for the index range 
any of the list and divide element of one list from corresponding element of other list:

```
First_List = [10, 2, 5, 4, 100]
Second_List = [5, 10, 20, 20, 25]
result = []

# get last index for the lists for iteration
end_index = len(First_List)

for i in range(end_index):
    result.append(First_List[i]/Second_List[i])
result
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 4.0]
```

This can be all done using list comprehension

```
result = [First_List[i]/ Second_List[i] for i in range(len(First_List))]
```

Alternatively, it can be done using zip and list comprehension (*which is better*).
For details you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418471/5916727):

```
result = [a/b for a,b in zip(First_List,Second_List)]
```

Comment: Thanks @open-source ! i got the answer .

Comment: It's generally better in Python to loop directly over the items in a list, rather than looping indirectly via indices. It's more efficient, and the code is less cluttered.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring Thanks , made an edit to add it.